# How to create Random Forest from scratch in R (without the randomforest package)

Tags: r, random-forest, rpart

This is the way I want to use Random Forest by using the `RandomForest` Package:

```
library (randomForest)
rf1 <- randomForest(CLA ~ ., dat, ntree=100, norm.votes=FALSE)
p1 <- predict(rf1, testing, type='response')
confMat_rf1 <- table(p1,testing_CLA$CLA)
accuracy_rf1 <- sum(diag(confMat_rf1))/sum(confMat_rf1)
```

I don't want to use the `RandomForest` Package at all. Given a dataset (`dat`) and using `rpart` and default values of `randomforest` package, how can I get the same results? For instance, for the 100 decision trees, I need to run the following:

```
for(i in 1:100){
cart.models[[i]]<-rpart(CLA~ ., data = random_dataset[[i]],cp=-1)
}
```

Where each `random_dataset[[i]]` would be randomly chosen default number of attributes and rows. In addition, does `rpart` used for `randomforest`?

Comment: Are you asking how to do random forests given only a decision tree package?  Why would you want to do this?  These packages have been optimized for use already.

Comment: Shalom @TimBiegeleisen, thanks! I have several reasons. One of them is demonstrating the process to my students and in addition I would like to control some parameters and change a bit the algorithm.

Comment: If you're feeling academic you could look at the source code for `randomForest`.  It wouldn't be as bad as you might expect.  Make sure you know the general algorithm before you go in there.

Comment: I would like to do it in R environment since I need to use some more functionality of R and other packages.

Comment: @Avi, you might find [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/04/complete-tutorial-tree-based-modeling-scratch-in-python/#nine) useful for demo content purposes

Comment: Also, there is a package [`partykit`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partykit/index.html) which provides infrastructures for creating tree from scratch

Comment: Thank you @Parth Chaudhary, but this is not what I'm looking for. I look for a way to simulate (mimic) the random forest algorithm step by step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to simulate training a random forest by training multiple trees using rpart and bootstrap samples on the training set and the features of the training set. 
The following code snippet trains 10 trees to classify the iris species and returns a list of trees with the out of bag accuracy on each tree.

```
library(rpart)
library(Metrics)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
library(ggplot2)


random_forest <- function(train_data, train_formula, method="class", feature_per=0.7, cp=0.01, min_split=20, min_bucket=round(min_split/3), max_depth=30, ntrees = 10) {

  target_variable <- as.character(train_formula)[[2]]
  features <- setdiff(colnames(train_data), target_variable)
  n_features <- length(features)

  ncores <- detectCores(logical=FALSE)
  cl <- makeCluster(ncores)
  registerDoParallel(cl)

  rf_model <- foreach(
    icount(ntrees),
    .packages = c("rpart", "Metrics")
  ) %dopar% {
    bagged_features <- sample(features, n_features * feature_per, replace = FALSE)
    index_bag <- sample(nrow(train_data), replace=TRUE)
    in_train_bag <- train_data[index_bag,]
    out_train_bag <- train_data[-index_bag,]
    trControl <- rpart.control(minsplit = min_split, minbucket = min_bucket, cp = cp, maxdepth = max_depth)
    tree <- rpart(formula = train_formula, 
                  data = in_train_bag, 
                  control = trControl)

    oob_pred <- predict(tree, newdata = out_train_bag, type = "class")
    oob_acc <- accuracy(actual = out_train_bag[, target_variable], predicted = oob_pred)

    list(tree=tree, oob_perf=oob_acc)
  }

  stopCluster(cl)

  rf_model

}

train_formula <- as.formula("Species ~ .")
forest <- random_forest(train_data = iris, train_formula = train_formula)
```